# Return normal terminal input when using tty, sys, terminos

Tags: python, input, terminal, sys, tty

I'm working on a little project which requiers input without "pausing" for each time.
Without completely understanding how it works, I used some code that I found online.

```
import tty, sys, termios

while True:
    filedescriptors = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
    tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin)
    dir_inp = 0
    while 1:
        dir_inp = sys.stdin.read(1)[0]
        if dir_inp != "q":
```

That is all the necessary code to allow for free input without pausing for confirmation or anything. At some point in the program I want the user to input a name, and the normal input() command no longer works...

Seeing as I'm unable to figure out how the code for this free input works, I'm also unable to figure out how to stop it...

(Usually I try my best to understand what I'm implementing in my code, but this is particularly tricky)

input() works just fine before the code shown above is run, but won't work once it's in action.

Comment: Maybe this is what you need https://github.com/folkien/pyIoCat ? I've written this project for COM communication testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed to PyInp, much easier

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question itself. You should probably post this as a comment to your question instead of as an answer.